# Inputbox input to streamwriter file

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter, inputbox

So, in my assignment, we're supposed to create phone directories in the `Directories.txt` file and then change the listings in the directories. I made a blank `directories.txt` file and placed that in the debug folder. I also have created a button titled `Create a New Phone Directory.` When a user clicks on it, the inputbox shows up prompting the user to title the new directory. I am wondering how to get the results from that inputbox that the user typed and  use that to create a new directory file in directories.txt and display it in a listbox. I think I have to use stream writer but every time I try, the result in the listbox shows up as `system.IO.streamwriter`.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    inputDirectories = InputBox("Please Enter the Name of the New Directory")
    If inputDirectories Is "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Directory Name")
    End If
    Dim fileDirectories As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText(inputDirectories)
    fileDirectories.WriteLine(inputDirectories)
End Sub
```

The assignment instructions say to use to write line method to add the name of the new file to the `directories.txt` file but I am totally lost on how to do this. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
'
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTestDirectory.txt"
Dim fileDirectories As System.IO.StreamWriter
Dim inputDirectory As String = ""
  '
  inputDirectory = InputBox("Please Enter the Name of the New Directory")
  If inputDirectory = "" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Directory Name")
  Else
    If System.IO.File.Exists(path) = False Then
      'The file does not exist so create a new file & add the inputted data
      fileDirectories = System.IO.File.CreateText(path)
      fileDirectories.WriteLine(inputDirectory)
      fileDirectories.Flush()
      fileDirectories.Close()
    Else
      'The file exists so append  file with the inputted data
      fileDirectories = System.IO.File.AppendText(path)
      fileDirectories.WriteLine(inputDirectory)
      fileDirectories.Flush()
      fileDirectories.Close()
    End If
  End If
  '
End Sub

Sub ReadDataBackNow()
  ' Open the file to read from one line at a time
  Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTestDirectory.txt"
  Dim DataStreamIn As System.IO.StreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(path)
  Dim TextLines As String = ""
  '
    Do While DataStreamIn.Peek() >= 0
      TextLines = TextLines & DataStreamIn.ReadLine()
    Loop
    DataStreamIn.Close()
    MsgBox(TextLines)
End Sub
```

## UPDATE

Update to answer additional question.
In your button click event add the following line

```
Listbox1.Items.Add(inputDirectory)
```

Add the line AFTER the inner IF THEN block so your code would like this

```
    If System.IO.File.Exists(path) = False Then
      'The file does not exist so create a new file & add the inputted data
      fileDirectories = System.IO.File.CreateText(path)
      fileDirectories.WriteLine(inputDirectory)
      fileDirectories.Flush()
      fileDirectories.Close()
    Else
      'The file exists so append  file with the inputted data
      fileDirectories = System.IO.File.AppendText(path)
      fileDirectories.WriteLine(inputDirectory)
      fileDirectories.Flush()
      fileDirectories.Close()
    End If
    Listbox1.Items.Add(inputDirectory)
```

Note that you will need several files to answer your question, so you may end up with something like

```
Directories.txt (contains list of directories)
   Friends_Directory.txt
   Workmates_Directory.txt
   Family_Directory.txt

 Friends_Directory.txt (contains list of friends)
   Bob 1234567890
   Angela 2345678901
   Steve 3456789012
   Ahmed 4567890123
   Fatima 5678901234

 Workmates_Directory.txt (contains list of workmates)
   CEO_Alan 0987654321
   Manager_Daisy 0876543219
   Foreman_Judy 0765432198
   Colleague_Jill 0654321987

 Family_Directory.txt
   Bro_Malcolm 1122334455
   Sis_Alisha 2233445566
   Moms 3344556677
   Pops 4455667788
   Uncle_Ben 5566778899
   Aunty_Sarah 6677889900
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I still have one more question. It's definitely adding my inputbox text into the textfile, but it's not adding the text into my listbox. how would i get the results into the lstbox?